# How can I use React/Node for accessing project files data with front end only?

Tags: reactjs, node.js, npm, frontend, react-scripts

### Background

---

I have a react web app with **front-end only**, that I build using the command `react-scripts build`. In order to route files without manually adding them to the code each time, I am using `@react-file-based-routing/react-router-dom` from `npm`.

I was wondering how this library works - how is it able to traverse the files in my project and add them to the router, and I wanted how to do something like this myself.

### The Question

---

My question, therefore, is how can I for example create a simple react page that simply shows the names of all files in a certain directory from my source project (when again, it's front end only so from my understanding this information must be gathered in the build process.

For example, if originally I chose the directory `mydir` and it contains `hello.txt, b.exe, file.mp4`, when accessing `mywebsite.com/showfiles` it should contain simple html (optionally with css,js) with a list of these three files.

**Side-Note:** If you think this can be done with Node.js alone without react tools (and without including new tools like webpack!) it would be cool, though I doubt it.

Comment: "I was wondering how this library works" – [with a Babel macro](https://github.com/onursagir/react-file-based-routing/blob/main/packages/react-router-dom/src/macro.ts) that [reads your file system structure](https://github.com/onursagir/react-file-based-routing/blob/main/packages/react-router-dom/src/get-routes-and-sources.ts#L19-L24) and generates react-router definitions. You can do the same.

Answer (score 0):

From a frontend app only, I think it is possible using the [file system API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileSystem) to browsers, but seems very limited. Seems it is also possible through chrome extensions, which has a specific [API](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/fileSystem/) for that and, of course, requires user permissions.

Accessing file system from backend you have more options, like [fs native module](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) and serving a [static file](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) from a HTTP app. You can also send a map from the folder structure to the frontend and make a navigation in the frontend as a folder navigation.